# javascript foo.call(object) vs. object.foo()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was looking on the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) and then i saw that they use `foo.call(context)` instead of `context.foo()`.
for example- assuming `this` is array they use:

```
return slice.call( this );
```

instead of:

```
return this.slice();
```

what is the difference and is it the prefer way (in terms of performance) doing those calls?

Comment: I doubt performance has anything to do. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I believe this has to do with the fact that you can pass a function like an object and as a result it may have a different name. So the context may not have the function by that same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that "foo" might not actually be a property of "context". When that's the case, the only real choice is to use `.call()` (or `.apply()`, as appropriate).

If you do have an object with a "foo" property that's a function, then there's no real reason to use `.call()`.

Comment: I often do this for the simple case of "maybe later". You never know, you might want to use `call` later... it's already there. Otherwise, there is no difference, performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Pointy's answer, the direct call of a member function seems to be much faster than Class.prototype.foo:

http://jsperf.com/javascript-foo-call-object-vs-object-foo